# Count based on field flag - How to do this in Lodash

Tags: arrays, typescript, lodash

I have an array with some objects. I would like to know how many elements in this array that has the field 'effective' set to true.

Here is my code now:

1) Array element object:

```
export class Record {
  public accuracy: string;
  public executed: boolean;
  public effective: boolean;
}
```

2) The array:

```
public records: Array<Record>;
```

3) The calculation part (this is the part I want to know how to improve by using Lodash)

```
  let sum: number = 0;
  for (const record of this.records) {
    if (record.effective) {
      sum++;
    }
  }
```

As you can see from my code above, what I am intend to do is to count the total number of elements in an array that have 'effective' field set to true.

How to do this in Lodash? Thanks.

Comment: could simply be `this.records.filter(record => record.effective).length` but that doesn't use lodash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`lodash#filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter) to retain the `effective` objects and then use [`lodash#size`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#size) to get the number of `effective` objects.

```
var result = _(records).filter('effective').size();
```

```js
var records = [
  { effective: true },
  { effective: true },
  { effective: false },
  { effective: true },
  { effective: false },
  { effective: true },
];

var result = _(records).filter('effective').size();
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **pullAllWith** to have more clean code as below

```
let effectiveRecords =<Record[]> _.pullAllWith(this.records,{effective : 'true'}, _.isEqual);
```

The count will be from

```
effectiveRecords.length
```